# How do you correctly calculate the Hessian of $(x^p + y^p)^{\frac1p}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, hessian-matrix

This is from Boyd and Vanderberghe's [Convex Optimization](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook), exercise 3.17. I gave an abbreviated version in the question title: what I'd really like to know is how to prove that $\nabla^2f \preceq 0$ for the function $f:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ $$f(x) = \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p\bigg)^{1/p}$$ where $p<1$ and $p \neq 0$, so that I can prove that it's concave. I found that $$\frac{\partial f^2}{\partial x_1^2} = \frac{(1-p)}{p^2} \bigg(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^p\bigg)^{(\frac{1}{p}-2)}$$

and that any second order derivative of $f$, and thus any element of $\nabla^2f$, is equal to this, since the expression treats all the $x_i$ identically.

However, this expression turns out to always be *positive* when $p<1$ and $p \neq 0$. So it proves the opposite of what the exercise asked me to prove! I feel like I must have missed a negative sign somewhere, but I can't find it for the life of me.

Comment: The derivative is wrong. You're skipping the chain rule.

Comment: That fixed it, thank you so much!!

Comment: Please provide the statement of the problem on B&V.

Comment: If $p<1$ then this partial derivative is non-positive due to the factor $(1-p)$.  Also you are neglecting the mixed partial derivatives

Comment: A crucial question! Do you consider only non-negative $x_{i}$'s ?? Because otherwise I think that is very difficult to get global concavity! And there is also a problem defining $f$ when $p=1/2k$.